# NGINX Get local IP for proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, localhost

Is it possible to pass in a variable such as `$server_addr` into proxy_pass.

```
proxy_pass      http://$server_addr:8096/;
```

If I do this, I run into issues where it doesn't load. Is this possible on what I'm doing?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Have you tried using `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I get bad gateway when I try to access the website. I need the local IP.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If I use localhost or 127.0.0.1, I get a bad gateway. The reason I want to use a variable is that I'm trying to make this dynamic rather than static.

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem the wrong way. You first need to start the web app which is supposed to be listening on that port, or fix its configuration so that it listens on the port you want.